# What is the use of switching? It seems missing when I surfacing web at home

Tags: networking, router, switching, osi

I'm trying to understand the OSI Model.

On layer 3, we normally have the router which is responsible to route traffic to corresponding host by ip address.

In my home, I have all my devices connected to a router(some wireless, some wired), I don't have a switch installed at home. It seems with the router is already routing the traffic by ip address by itself, where is the layer 2 (switch) ?

Of course, I think switch must be involved somewhere, I just don't know. Can someone also explain how router and switch work together? It seems to me switch is useless, because router can already connect device, route traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Most consumer-grade routers include an integrated switch, ie. they have more than a single LAN port.

A simple switch is plug and play - you just connect all devices to the switch and the can talk to each other. Using a router to connect a local network would be a pain - you'd have to manually assign IP addresses to all its ports and to the connected device. Automatic IP addresses through DHCP rely on a functional layer 2 (ie. switched or shared L2 segment) and doesn't work over routed links.

However, simple doesn't mean useless. Switches are required to expand a single routed uplink into a number of ports that you can connect devices to.

Additionally, there are very sophisticated switches you can use to build a large and powerful network (more advanced switches can also route while switching).